# Slick with H2: tables are missing

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, slick, in-memory-database, h2db

I'm writing an app using **slick** and **h2 in-memory db**. 
I'd like to check how my data is written to db by creating database config in **IntelliJ idea**, but all the **tables are missing**.

---

Here is my code:

application.conf

```
h2mem = {
  url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=MYSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"
  driver = org.h2.Driver
  connectionPool = disabled
}
```

Repository.scala

```
....
class TaskTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Task](tag, "TASK") {
    def id = column[Long]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

    def startTime = column[LocalTime]("START_TIME")

    override def * = (id.?, startTime) <> (Task.tupled, Task.unapply)
}
....
```

Main.scala

```
....
 val db = Database.forConfig("h2mem")
 val repo= new Repo(H2Profile)
 db.run(repo.createTaskTable)
 ...
```

And Idea config: 
    [image]

Comment: It seems you forgot to include `createTaskTable` function in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple connections to a named in-memory h2 database are allowed only from the same virtual machine. You must start a [TCP server](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#using_server) in order to be able to connect via IntelliJ IDEA.

More about in-memory connection [here](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases)
More about connection modes [here](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#connection_modes)